# Using (ceiling . sqrt) in range causes error

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Hasekll a few days ago and was playing around with ranges when I ran into a cryptic error while trying a quick and dirty prime number checker.

```
isprime n = all ((<) 0)  [n `rem` k | k <- [2..n-1]] -- okay
isprime' n = all ((<) 0)  [n `rem` k | k <- [2..(ceiling . sqrt) n]] -- compiles but busted
```

Example:

```
Prelude> isprime 19
True

Prelude> isprime' 19

<interactive>:46:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘isprime'’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Floating a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    • In the expression: isprime' 19
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = isprime' 19

<interactive>:46:10: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘19’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘isprime'’, namely ‘19’
      In the expression: isprime' 19
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = isprime' 19
```

So I checked the following, and both turn out as expected.

```
Prelude> [rem 19 k | k <- [2.. 19-1]] 
[1,1,3,4,1,5,3,1,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

Prelude> [rem 19 k | k <- [2..(ceiling . sqrt) 19]] 
[1,1,3,4]
```

Can anyone help me understand the issue? If there is a good section in the online Haskell tutorials, would appreciate a pointer. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using the [right section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) `(> 0)` instead of `((<) 0)` - it reads more naturally.

Comment: you can sidestep the whole conversion problem with ```isprime'' n = all (0 <)  [n `rem` k | k <- takeWhile (\i -> i*i <= n) [2..] ]```

Comment: by the way you need to add a special case for `isprime* 1 = False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an explicit conversion, instead:

```
[2..(ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral) n]
```

Otherwise, you are calling `sqrt` on the type of `n`, forcing that type to be a `Floating`. The rest of the code already requires `n` to have some `Integral` type.

These two requirements can not be satisfied: standard numeric types are either floating point, or fixed point (`Integral`, roughly).

It would also greatly help if you started to write your functions from their type annotations. This prevents GHC to infer a type which was not intended -- when that happens errors are detected much later on, causing confusion.

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps a lot. I did start with an initial type annotation isprime::Integer <- Bool, but a different error showed up, presumably because of the contradiction you mentioned.